# Why is my name shown on my flagged questions list?

Tags: discussion, support

When I look at the list of the questions I've flagged, right next to the reason of the flag, my name is displayed.

[image]

What is the reason of that?

I cannot see why my name is displayed there

1. My name is displayed on the top of the list.
2. The list is displayed when I look at my profile and click on the 'helpful flags' link, so who else's flags could they have been?

Answer (score 3):

The question is really, why not? It rarely hurts to have more information. Also, that's the way mods see it, and though a mod is unlikely to forget whose profile he's looking at, it's easier to have it right there. And it's the same format we see on the all-flags page (minus the other flaggers), so it's probably easier for the devs to display.

Comment: I wonder whose name it shows on a profile that's been merged...